# Scripting upgrade of Nexus 2.14.2 to 3.2

Tags: nexus, sonatype

I am going to upgrade Nexus 2 to Nexus 3 and have read the documentation about [upgrading to Nexus 3.2](https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference3/upgrading.html) and it only mention using the upgrade wizard.

is it possible to do the same thing by writing a script or using some command line tool? I am going to upgrade several nexus installations and if it where possible to do it using a script it would save me a lot of time.

---

Update:
I have gotten response from Sonatype that there is no command line / REST interface that you can use to migrate from Nexus 2 to Nexus 3. You need to use the GUI migration wizard.

Comment: add it as your own answer

Comment: Update: I have gotten response from Sonatype that there is no command line / REST interface that you can use to migrate from Nexus 2 to Nexus 3. You need to use the GUI migration wizard.